# Why does my SLOG slow down sequential sync writes?

Tags: zfs

I jury-rigged a TrueNAS server to run a few tests in preparation for a proper NAS build. I got hold of an older Xeon server with 256GB RAM and a 10GbE NIC, equipped it with 6 sata disks configured as 3 mirror vdevs and installed the latest TrueNAS Core version. I also added a single 850 Pro SSD as SLOG (I know - it's just for a rough performance test).

The dataset is mounted via NFS (with default settings, i.e. sync enabled) and **bonnie++** was used to test read and write performance. Results were roughly as expected but as soon as I removed the SLOG from the pool the block sequential write performance increased by a factor of five (480M/s vs 107M/s). Everything else remained equal.

I don't understand how ZFS arranges the ZIL across pool-disks when no SLOG is present but even if it can use the throughput of all six spinning disks I would expect it to be slower than the nominal 500MB/s provided by the SSD.

I found an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/issues/1012) that seems to explain such behaviour but it was resolved some time ago. Is there another explanation?

**Edit (answering questions in comments and further tests):**

`sync` is set to `standard`, I left all params at their default values (except `atime=off`, `compression=on`).

The `dd` and `fio` tests as suggested by *shodanshok* gave consistent results: ~570kB/s with SLOG vs ~380kB/s without, as one would expect.

I ran a few more `fio` workloads and will show the SLOG / NOSLOG speedup for each them below. Each of those was without `oflag=sync`, but due to the NFS sync mount there should still be syncs at the end of each file or loop cycle:

- `--rw=write --loop=1000 --size=8k`: 1.67
- `--rw=write --loop=10 --size=32M`: **0.44**
- `--rw=write --loop=1 --size=1G`: 1.07

I did not do any further bonnie++ testing since there's an additional complication I did not mention initially: bonnie++ allocates a file twice as large as system memory, to reduce caching effects. Since my test machine has huge amounts of RAM I ran the test in a memory limited cgroup (memory.limit_in_bytes=4G). There seems to be some interaction going on between the memory limit, the large file write and the SLOG/ZIL which I don't understand.

Comment: Can you try with `dd` and `fio`? ie: something as `dd if=/dev/urandom of=/your/path/test.img bs=4k count=8192 oflag=sync` and `fio --name=test --filename=/your/path/test.img --rw=randwrite --fsync=1 size=32M`

Comment: Are you testing a realistic or representative workload? Also, what are your ZFS filesystem settings; specifically the `sync` parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Large sequential sync writes can be efficiently served by your main pool disks (and you have 6 of them vs single SSD), while SLOG is mainly useful for small *random* sync writes. Moreover, the SSD you are using as SLOG is not particularly fast at doing sync writes (it has no power loss protected DRAM cache).

Your `bonnie++` results seems skewed by client or server side caching, so I would discard them. As best practice, always evaluate your system performance with some real world workloads.